# PHP doesn't execute Login Form MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Recently, I was making a login and signup page, where a mail gets sent if you sign up to confirm your account. I used MySQL for the account list, and have a 'confirm' column with 0 (unconfirmed) or 1 (confirmed).

Now, I created the following script to login, but it doesn't seem to be working. After executing this script, I see the "Processing...", then I see the "Such Sadness" part. I have checked in PHPMyAdmin that the account exists, and that it is actually confirmed. MySQL_Base is the file with the connection to the database, and that file is included in other files where the script works.

What is exactly the problem here?

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
include("mysql_base.php");
echo "Processing...<br>";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages_accounts WHERE confirm='1' AND email='".$email."' AND pass='".$password."' LIMIT 1";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) &&  $result->num_rows > 0){
  echo "FOUND UR ACCOUNT. MUCH HAPPINESS. SUCH GLAD. WOW REDIRECTING...";
} else {
  echo "SUCH SADNESS. NO ACCOUNT WITH SUCH NAME. WEIRD RETURN. WOW. WHY NOT <a href='loginSignup.php'>SIGNUP</a>?";
}
```

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions. Those are two separate libraries, and don't work together.

Comment: @andrewsi Where have I mixed them up?

Comment: `if(mysql_fetch_array($query) !== `

Comment: @andrewsi I just tried replacing `mysql_fetch_array` with `mysqli_fetch_array`. Doesn't work.

Comment: Be aware that your code is *wide open* to **SQL injection attacks**.  Basically any user can execute any arbitrary SQL code they want on your server.

Comment: @pokekart2002 - look at Alex's answer. You're making _2_ calls to the result set in your code, and if there's only one matching row in the database, the second call won't return anything.

Comment: @David How? I'm.. Well.. Pretty new to MySQL.

Comment: @pokekart2002: Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php And look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php  The general rule is that you never want to put user input directly into your SQL queries.  That results in executing user input *as code*.  Treat user input as values, not as executable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace these 3 lines:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
if(mysql_fetch_array($query) !== false){
```

with this one:

```
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) &&  $result->num_rows > 0){
```

**UPDATE** Last version after discussion in chat:

```
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) { 
   if ($result->num_rows > 0){ 
      echo "FOUND UR ACCOUNT. MUCH HAPPINESS. SUCH GLAD. WOW REDIRECTING..."; 
   } else { 
      echo "SUCH SADNESS. NO ACCOUNT WITH SUCH NAME. WEIRD RETURN. WOW. WHY NOT <a href='loginSignup.php'>SIGNUP</a>?"; 
   } 
} else { 
   echo "Errormessage: %s\n". mysqli_connect_error(); 
}
```

Comment: Compact. And it works. Thank you. It IS supposed to be `!=` right?

Comment: No, I would suggest to switch your `echo`s. The way when `true` should be the first one

Comment: Is that better, than doing `!=`? If so why? It is basically the same thing, if my knowledge is correct...

Comment: that is absolutely up to you :-) your project, your code :-) I like more PDO object variant than mysqli. so it is just personal preferences :-)

Comment: Now what? I tried adding a few more pieces of code, and it showed up as `Undefined Variable: result in ...`. The code works, but it's kinda annoying. I removed all the code, copy and pasted it from this page, and tried again. Same result. What could be the solution?

Comment: @pokekart2002 post your new code fragment as new question :-)

Comment: Couldn't be bothered. Same topic, so I edited the question. Ignore how I haven't switched the `echo`s around yet, but it always shows up as FOUND UR ACCOUNT.

Comment: because you didn't switch `echo`s for positive and negative flow for condition I provided. and did you change table definition? why did you change `password='".$password."'` to `pass='".$password."'` ?

Comment: Yes I changed the Table, because it appeared to be a little buggy using PASSWORD as a column name. Alright, I switched the echo's around. Still. Same problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92889/discussion-between-pokekart2002-and-alex).